# Is there a way to get at the queries used in the MBV / BHM

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, mbv, bhm

Is there a way to get at/extract the queries used in the Message Box Viewer / BizTalk Health Monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the SQL queries:

The MBV Q&A file mentions this

```
Q: Where do the SQL queries executed by MBV come from ?
A: Some of them come directly from BizTalk Architect Lee Graber’s "Advanced Queries" 
   document. Other queries come from Microsoft BizTalk Support teams or known SQL & 
   BizTalk Troubleshooting documents.
```

The .doc file with the paper can be found [here](http://home.comcast.net/~sdwoodgate/BizTalkServer2004AdvancedMessageBoxQueries.doc) (mirror site I found):

Another way to do this, would be to use [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to see what commands are being sent to SQL to see which queries are being executed.

Answer (score 2):

No.  They're all baked into an assembly.

If this is related to the previous question about the ESX warning, my recommendation would be to modify the output which is just an HTML page to remove of annotate the warning.

Comment: The tip about changing the rules in BHM worked, so the ESX warning doesn't appear

Answer (score 2):

The SQL queries used by BHM or MBV come from a declarative repository and also from an assembly containing .NET code.
These queries are not public; if you want to see them, you can indeed use SQL profiler.

BHM and MBV use also .BAT, .VBS, WMI and PS queries. We also did not make these queries public.

JP
MBV/BHM team